# Powershell $_ operator is an unexpected token

Tags: powershell

i am trying to use the following command to convert files from one format to another using a tool, but powershell gives me an error:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\myself\Desktop\VECTORS\ -Recurse -Include "*.eps" | % { "C:\Program Files\UniConvertor-2.0rc4\uniconvertor.exe" $_.FullName }
```

The error is

```
Unexpected token '$_' in expression or statement.
```

i thought that the $_ operator evaluates to the item in a piped command?

Comment: I believe it's not seeing it as an expression to execute and more of a faulty string concatenation.  Have you tried &{} or wrapping in subexpression ()?

Comment: Put `&` in front of the `uniconvertor.exe` path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This comes up a lot.  The error message isn't very helpful.  You can't run something with a quote as the first character.  Here's a lesser known workaround:

```
C":\Program Files\UniConvertor-2.0rc4\uniconvertor.exe"
```

Usually the answer is this.  It's what tab completion will give you:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\UniConvertor-2.0rc4\uniconvertor.exe'
```